# Html5 - multiple elements with H1

Tags: html

Have I got this wrong?

The new elements that html5 brought allowed us to use headers within sections, nav etc. Does this apply to H1? And if it is allowed - does it make bad SEO sense?

The reason I ask is that most, if not all, the SEO ranking tools out there, tell me to remove duplicate H1's from my code. It's a good few years since the introduction of these new elements so I would have though the major tools would be up to date with the structure.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: H1 should be used as main title, or very important topic on your page. So, you should have only one H1 tag per page. In most cases, its title of some blog post or page. H1 represents short description of page and its directly related with content. So, multiple H1 tags is bad practice.

Comment: Your comment is entirely accurate with respect to xHTML 1, HTML 4.01, HTML 3.2 etc. @Aleksandar - but HTML5 has set out to do something different with document heading outlines from its predecessors. (That's not to say HTML5's attempt to reinvent document outlines will necessarily gain any traction.)

Comment: I agree, but, as I say, it's bad practice. H1 should always be page title that represent short description of page content. In that way, user will know what if topic of that page and RSS reader will render page propertly. If you need to have bigger text font for something, you can always use H3 with custom css class. it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You have it right.

*Theoretically*, you can have multiple `<h1>s` in HTML5.

*Theoretically*, each `<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>` etc. in HTML5 can have its own heading outline, starting with its own `<h1>`.

In practice, however, UAs do not - and might never - comprehend that kind of outline (unique to HTML5).

The best summary I've read is by Steve Faulkner, an **Editor** at **W3C**:

**The HTML5 Document Outline** (*28 October, 2013*) by Steve Faulkner

http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/